# Sharepoint Solution showing old server url while debugging in visual studio 2010

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, debugging

I have a SharePoint solution which I developed in a server named HostA, and was deployed in the same server at the url, `http://HostA:2100/ASD`

Later I moved the entire solution to a new server HostB, and i restored the entire site. And I got my site working at the url `http://HostB:2100/ASD`. I did change the url properties for the project before deploying the solution.

However whenever i click debug, the new window opened will refer the old url, that is `http://HostA:2100/ASD`. How can I change that to reference the new Url, that is `http://HostB:2100/ASD`.

Comment: Did you clean and re-build the solution and project, before deploying? Also, this information is saved in a file called [ProjectName].csproj.user/[ProjectName].vbproj.user - make sure it has the correct URL

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I am not sure whether I clean it before deploying... Let me have a go at it. Again its a c# project, where can I find that file?

Comment: Suppose you have project in E drive, the file should be here: E:\visual studio 2010\Projects\ [SolutionName]\ [ProjectName]\ [ProjectName].csproj.user

Comment: Thanks, however I believe i got the right url over there too...  `<SharePointSiteUrl>http://HostB:2100/ASD/</SharePointSiteUrl>`

Comment: cool, then just clean the solution and re-deploy it... it should work fine - because it just keeps the target site URL in that place only!

Comment: No Luck ... Still referring the old url :(

Comment: :( - Sorry Amrutha, couldn't help you up!

Comment: no problem, now after hitting the debug button i manually replace the url :) so break points are hitting :)